# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {guid} failed due to the following error: XXXX Class not registered + Office 365

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I am building SharePoint auto-hosted app. In that I have used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word dll. I have published app to the Office-365 environment. When my code reaches to the line where I am initializing the interop object it throws this error.

Line:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application ap = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

And Error I got :

```
Error in Default page: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException(0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
  at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
  at DocumentAppTestWeb.Pages.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

When I run my app by pressing `F5` it runs perfectly.
But when I publish my `.app` file to the app catalog of my Office 365 environment it gives me above error.

Is there any option that I can use?
Any help will be appreciated..!

Comment: It looks like the component you're trying to initialize either isn't installed on your machine, has a damaged installation or needs to be registered.

Comment: On the reference to excel change in properties `Copy Local` to `True` and try to publish the dll too

Comment: @AccessDenied I check my machine I have installed Office 2013 and is working fine. But I don't know how to register it in my registry.?

Comment: @AccessDenied I have updated my question. Can you please check it?

Comment: @rudym I tried to change the `Copy Local` property. But it is disabled. By default it is false. And how can I change that property. I think that the issue I am facing has the solution in your comment.

Comment: by removing the that excel assembly from the GAC you should enable this property

Comment: Do I understand the question correclty that you want to use Office Interop on a server? Don't do this! Office interop is only designed to work on a client machine. Read this for more information: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us)

Comment: @cremor I want to use Office Interop in my SharePoint auto-hosted app. And the app can be installed on SharePoint 2013 environment. Currently I am using it in my Office365 environment. I check the link you provided but Open XML cannot convert word to pdf.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this was going to a local problem on your PC! :) Interop connects to functionality found on the computer  program or assembly (which supports COM).

[Installing and Using the Office 2003 Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159923%28office.11%29.aspx)
(This is an older version of office, but is about the same process.)
Be sure you have installed all right :)

Comment: Hi. I have updated my question. Can you please check it?